# How to travel from Cincinnati

Tags: usa

What is the cheapest and quickest solution to travel from Cincinnati to Boston? I have driven the route through Buffalo using I90

Comment: Cheapest and quickest are mutually exclusive. Cheapest is hitchhiking, but this is not quick; quickest is chartering a private jet, but this is not cheap. Can you be more specific as to what you are looking for?

Comment: @MichaelHampton Stealing a private jet would probably meet both criteria?

Comment: If you book far enough in advance, I'm seeing airline prices at $145 and under. What's your price point? This is kind of a subjective question.

Comment: @Doc A fighter jet would be faster.

Comment: @PeterM Significantly lower probability of making it there alive though...

Comment: Even faster if they [pick you up](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fulton_surface-to-air_recovery_system) at your house and you jump out of the plane when you get there.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the cheaper you get, the less likely you are to be quick. Here's some options in order from cheapest to most expensive.

- **Hitchhiking**. The cheapest option since it's technically free. It's highly likely that you'll take quite some time getting there, however. It's not the safest option either, especially for solo travellers. (As suggested by @MichaelHampton in the comments.)
- **Bus**. Taking a bus, like a Greyhound, can run as cheap as $113. Sites like [Wanderu](https://www.wanderu.com/en/bus-tickets/us-ma/boston/us-oh/cincinnati/) can help you compare bus schedules. It'll take somewhere in the neighborhood of 20+ hours, depending on the schedule. [Rome2rio](http://www.rome2rio.com/s/Cincinnati/Boston) claims you can do the trip for $85.
- **Train**. If you can get to Cleveland, there's a once daily Amtrack train to Boston via Buffalo, the [Lakeshore Limited](https://m.amtrak.com/mt/www.amtrak.com/lake-shore-limited-train). It takes 13 hours. Costs depends on how far out you book; tomorrow is $150 but a random Wednesday in August was $80.
- **Plane**. You can get to Boston in a very roundabout way by flying Cincinnati-Washington and then Washington-Boston with American Airlines. I picked a random Wednesday in September when doing my flight search, and it cost $147. Total travel time varies depending on how long the layover is; flying time is 3 hours.

Other options like chartering a jet are clearly more expensive.

I've not included just driving, mostly because I have no idea how much gas would cost.

Answer (score 0):

It is 883 miles from Cincinnati to Boston.  You can fly in two hours for about $145, or you can take the bus for $90 but spend 21 hours doing it.  Any other alternative would be much, much more expensive.